# how to manage my files in drupal

Tags: drupal

I have created a web page whereby a user let's say userA sends a post to the Administrator by means of filling up a form and upload any form of media. I have installed file module, and userA is able to upload any media. Now my problem is when userB wants to view the available posts. he can see all the content but then not being able to preview images it's just showing up as a link or the name of the image and it's extension.

Is there a module or a way which I can use to be able to manage my files whereby I can provide a download link for attached files and also being able to display images.

Comment: Are you using a view to show all the medias?

Comment: Yes I am using views to show all the medials.

Comment: Can userA see the media preview when they are looking at the available posts?

Comment: @Quint , not userA cannot peview the images on available posts as well

Comment: What formatter do you have selected for the image field in the view? If everybody is seeing the same thing, that may be set to just display a link. Just change it to use the Image formatter. If you need both the image and a download link, you can add the field twice with different formatters.